# How do I run a C program from VIM?

Tags: c, vim

Is there a way to compile and run a C program from VIM without typing its filename ?

Answer (score 131):

`:!gcc -o somename % && ./somename`
When using `:!`, % will be substituted by the name of the currently opened file.

When your project becomes larger, you can also write a makefile and compile the current project with `:make`, if there are any errors, vim will jump to them automatically.

Comment: I like you answer. I want to make it final. Please guide.

Comment: @Coder: No, you can accept the answer.  Just click the check.  You don't need any amount of votes for that.

Answer (score 67):

Use the following mapping code in your .vimrc file for compiling and running a c programming file.

```
 map <F8> : !gcc % && ./a.out <CR>
```

F8 key is for run the mapping. "%" is to take the current file name.

Or, if you want to save the current file before compiling it, use

```
map <F8> :w <CR> :!gcc % && ./a.out <CR>
```

Or more ideally, if you want to use the file basename not the default 'a.out' as the executable file name, use the following:

```
map <F8> :w <CR> :!gcc % -o %< && ./%< <CR>
```

In the above command, "<" after "%" removes extension and dot (foo.c => foo), so "%<" is the file basename.

You can find this and similar infos in cmdline.txt. Command in vim:`help: cmdline.txt`. You can also find specific details about the use of "%" by using [`:help filename-modifiers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers)in vim.

Comment: Please note that a space character is a valid normal-mode command that moves the cursor one space to the right. Thus the space between the two ex commands you've chained together in your second mapping will move the cursor if possible before compiling. If moving the cursor to the right fails then the compilation step will never run.

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR** No Makefile is required, tweaking `&makeprg` is also completely useless, and yet `:make %<` is enough to compile from Vim.

**Long answer:**

I duplicate an answer I gave in a closed "duplicate question".

Considering we are using vim, and not vi, `:make` is the way to go.

On **Linux**-like (it also applies to **cygwin**, but **not to mingw** on windows -- in mingw case, see the other answers that alter `&makeprg`, leave it alone otherwise) systems where gnumake is installed, if you don't have a Makefile in your project, and if your project is made of only one file, just type `:make %<`. It will be enough (you can play with `$CXXFLAGS`, `$CFLAGS`, `$LDFLAGS` (for `-Llib/path` options) and `$LDLIBS` (for `-llibname` options) to tune the compilation options). Then to run the program, type `:!./%<`, or with latter versions of vim, run `:terminal ./%<`.

If your project is made of several files, then you'll need a Makefile to take advantage of `:make`.

If you manage your project with CMake, and if you compile your project in a directory (or several -> debug, release, ...) outside the sources tree, then the integration will require a plugin. AFAIK, I'm the only one to propose such a plugin: [BuildToolsWrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/cmake.md) integrates the management of CMake (choice of the build directory, possibility to chose between the debug, or release, or whatever build directory). It has to be coupled with one of the [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/local_vimrc.vim) plugin.

In all cases, calling directly the compiler from within (or outside) Vim with `:!g++ -o %< %` or whatever is what we used to do 15 years ago on vi. Vim has a wonderful feature: it can integrate (yes, like in IDE) the compiler. See `:h quickfix`. Navigating between errors directly from the editor is much easier than extracting one error line with our eyes, typing back the line number into the editor, going back to the shell to see what exactly was rejected, ... It may be enough in C, but In C++ when we are "trying to call an overload that doesn't exist", we can't work this way (switching back and forth between the editor and the shell).

Finally, if you want to compile on a single keystroke those mono-file projects, you can add in your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> <f7> :make %<<cr>
```

If you want to adapt automatically the compilation command depending of the kind of project mono-file pet project, or real world multi-file project, well, more wiring is needed, and this is what [BTW does](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/make_run.md) -- it reads various options to know what to do.

Last note: `&makeprg` is best left alone, at least not set to g++/gcc/clang/clang++/gfortran/... Because, every time you change your language, you'll have to change it (unless you use `:setlocal`). With the solution I recommend, if I want to use clang++ instead of g++, all I have to do is to set: `:let $CXX='clang++'` (or `$CC` in C), and then call `:make %<`. I can even define `:let $CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'` to compile in C++11 -- the same variable will be used to turn warnings on, to use a sanitizer, etc.

Comment: I see. This answer was on [a question that was closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474662) as a duplicate to the current question.

Comment: Indeed, I've posted here because the other Q/A is marked as duplicate and closed. And yet all the answers I see here are quite inefficient (direct call of gcc without using the quickfix window, or they set `makeprg` whilst it isn't required with a properly configured gnumake).

Comment: i was using a shortcut mapped to !gcc blah blah which closes the editor and runs gcc or the compiled file untill.... i saw this answer. I was actually just overlooking the answer. But, the phrase 'what we used to do 15 years ago on vi' grabbed my attention. The make without make file with integrated op/compiler message is superb. I just loved it. Can't thank u enough.

Comment: Contd... if we use the same command in vim inside terminal emulator then vim will use the terminal to compile. So Gvim is much useful in this case.

Comment: @AbinashDash. You're welcome! :) However, I'm not sure to understand your last comment. So far, I'm always using gvim (for a better keyboard support), and I compile with `:make` to make (sic) sure errors directty go into the quickfix windows. I don't find any advantage to use the terminal emulator as we'd still have to parse (with our eyes) hundred of errors before jumping to the right one. (Note, thanks to my BuildToolsWrapper plugin I've had background compilation for ages, and I've even added support for colours in error messages in a recent commit)

Comment: I just added a little footnote for people who would expect the same behaviour of the command(opening a beautifully integrated terminal) in vim. I avoided using Gvim because of transperency issues and didnt bother fixing it. So I kept usin vim in terminal. But I think I can fix that isuue with some x11 app(may be xcompmgr?) that set tranparency for GTK apps and enjoy Gvim instead of vim.  My 2nd comment was some what confusing. But I truly agree with you on usage of Gvim over vim.

Comment: WELL everytime I am  using any of the methods stated over here by any of you guys I am getting `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (./\learning_c\library)
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...` how to fix this?

Comment: @AnaghBasak, As you're under windows, you can try `:!%:p` instead. I don't remember the subtleties about how to reference a file in the current directory which isn't in the `%PATH%`

Answer (score 12):

It's 2018 now, vim 8 has released for 2 years and shipped with all the Linux distributions and Mac OS X. But a lot of vim tutorials are still teaching people something ten years ago.

You can compile your C++/Java programs in vim as convenience as Sublime Text or NotePad++ with some dedicated plugins for Vim 8 or NeoVim.

For example, the [AsyncRun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) plugin will allow you run shell commands in background and read output from quickfix window in realtime.
[See the screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gImp.gif).

Just like compiling programs in IDEs, the compilation errors will be matched by errorformat and be highlighted and become selectable. You can navigate errors in the quickfix window or continue editing while compiling.

**Quick setup**

Copy & paste the lines below to your vimrc:

```
Plug 'skywind3000/asyncrun.vim'

" open quickfix window automatically when AsyncRun is executed
" set the quickfix window 6 lines height.
let g:asyncrun_open = 6

" ring the bell to notify you job finished
let g:asyncrun_bell = 1

" F10 to toggle quickfix window
nnoremap <F10> :call asyncrun#quickfix_toggle(6)<cr>
```

When you input “:AsyncRun echo hello ” in the command line:

[see the capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi0Db.png)

You will see the realtime command output in the open quickfix window.

**Compile and run a single file**

Compiling a single file with AsyncRun is much simpler than Sublime Text’s build system. We can setup F9 for this:

```
noremap <silent> <F9> :AsyncRun gcc -Wall -O2 "$(VIM_FILEPATH)" -o "$(VIM_FILEDIR)/$(VIM_FILENOEXT)" <cr>
```

The macros in `$(..)` form will be expanded as the real file name or directory, and then we will have F5 to run the executable:

```
noremap <silent> <F5> :AsyncRun -raw -cwd=$(VIM_FILEDIR) "$(VIM_FILEDIR)/$(VIM_FILENOEXT)" <cr>
```

The double quotation mark is used to handle path names containing spaces. The option `-cwd=$(VIM_FILEDIR)` means running the file in the file's directory. The absolute path name `$(VIM_FILEDIR)/$(VIM_FILENOEXT)` is used because linux needs a `./` prefix to running executables in current directory, but windows doesn't . Using the absolute path name of the binary file can handle this crossing platform issue.

Another option `-raw` means the output will not be matched by vim's errorformat, and will be displayed in quickfix as what it is. Now you can compile your file with F9, check the compilation errors in quickfix window and press F5 to run the binary.

**Build C/C++ Projects**

No matter what build tool you are using, make or cmake, project building means acting to a group of files. It requires locating the project root directory. AsyncRun uses a simple method called root markers to identify the project root. The Project Root is identified as the nearest ancestor directory of the current file which contains one of these directories or files:

```
let g:asyncrun_rootmarks = ['.svn', '.git', '.root', '_darcs']
```

If none of the parent directories contains these root markers, the directory of the current file is used as the project root. This enables us to use either `<root>` or `$(VIM_ROOT)` to represent the project root. and F7 can be setup to build the current project:

```
noremap <silent> <F7> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> make <cr>
```

What if your current project is not in any git or subversion repository ? How to find out where is my project root ? The solution is very simple, just put an empty .root file in your project root, it will be located easily.

Let’s move on, setup F8 to run the current project:

```
noremap <silent> <F8> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> -raw make run <cr>
```

The project will run in its root directory. Of course, you need define the run rule in your own makefile. then remap F6 to test:

```
noremap <silent> <F6> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> -raw make test <cr>
```

If you are using cmake, F4 can be map to update your Makefile:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F4> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> cmake . <cr>
```

Due to the implementation of c runtime, if the process is running is a non-tty environment, all the data in stdout will be buffered until process exits. So, there must be a `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` statement if you want to see the real-time output. or you can close the stdout buffer at the beginning by

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

At the mean time, if you are writing C++ code, a std::endl can be appended to the end of std::cout. It can force flush the stdout buffer. If you are developing on windows, AsyncRun can open a new cmd window for the child process:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :AsyncRun -cwd=$(VIM_FILEDIR) -mode=4 "$(VIM_FILEDIR)/$(VIM_FILENOEXT)" <cr>
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> -mode=4 make run <cr>
```

Using the option `-mode=4` on windows will open a new prompt window to run the command, just like running command line programs in Visual Studio. Finally, we have these key mappings below:

- F4: update Makefile with cmake.
- F5: run the single file
- F6: run project test
- F7: build project
- F8: run project
- F9: compile the single file
- F10: toggle quickfix window

It is more like build system in NotePad++ and GEdit. If you are using cmake heavily, you can write a simple shell script located in `~/.vim/script/build.sh` to combine F4 and F7 together: it will update Makefile if CMakeList.txt has been changed, then exectute make.

**Advanced usage**

You can also define shell scripts in your dotfiles repository and execute the script with F3:

```
nnoremap <F3> :AsyncRun -cwd=<root> sh /path/to/your/dotfiles/script/build_advanced.sh <cr>
```

The following shell environment variables are defined by AsyncRun:

```
$VIM_FILEPATH  - File name of current buffer with full path
$VIM_FILENAME  - File name of current buffer without path
$VIM_FILEDIR   - Full path of current buffer without the file name
$VIM_FILEEXT   - File extension of current buffer
$VIM_FILENOEXT - File name of current buffer without path and extension
$VIM_CWD       - Current directory
$VIM_RELDIR    - File path relativize to current directory
$VIM_RELNAME   - File name relativize to current directory 
$VIM_ROOT      - Project root directory
$VIM_CWORD     - Current word under cursor
$VIM_CFILE     - Current filename under cursor
$VIM_GUI       - Is running under gui ?
$VIM_VERSION   - Value of v:version
$VIM_COLUMNS   - How many columns in vim's screen
$VIM_LINES     - How many lines in vim's screen
$VIM_SVRNAME   - Value of v:servername for +clientserver usage
```

All the above environment variables can be used in your `build_advanced.sh`. Using the external shell script file can do more complex work then a single command.

**Grep symbols**

Sometimes, If you don't have a well setup environment in you remote linux box, grep is the most cheap way to search symbol definition and references among sources. Now we will have F2 to search keyword under cursor:

```
if has('win32') || has('win64')
    noremap <F2> :AsyncRun! -cwd=<root> grep -n -s -R <C-R><C-W> --include='*.h' --include='*.c*' '<root>' <cr>
else
    noremap <F2> :AsyncRun! -cwd=<root> findstr /n /s /C:"<C-R><C-W>" "\%CD\%\*.h" "\%CD\%\*.c*" <cr>
endif
```

The above script will run grep or findstr in your project root directory, and find symbols in only `.c`, `.cpp` and `.h` files. Now we move around the cursor and press F2, the symbol references in current project will be displayed in the quickfix window immediately.

This simple keymap is enough for most time. And you can improve this script to support more file types or other grep tools in your vimrc .

That’s the practical way to build/run C/C++ projects in Vim 8 or NeoVim. Just like Sublime Text’s build system and NotePad++’s NppExec.

No more outdated vim tutorials again, try something new.

Answer (score 6):

since most of the time you would use a Makefile, in addition to the given answers, I also like to see my results in a "cleared" screen:

`map <F10> :w<CR> :!clear; make<CR> :!./%<<CR>`

- `:w<CR>` saves the file
- `:!clear; make<CR>` clears the screen and runs `make`
- `:!./%<<CR>` runs a program (`%`) without the extension (`<`)

Comment: This is really quite cool! I edited it a bit for my own needs. I got rid of the initial "Press ENTER or type command to continue" with 'silent !clear...'. I also made a separator between the "compiling" area and the "running" area. I put quotes around the file name to avoid issues with spaces. And lastly I put the time command in there for some extra useful output. Here's my version:
 
`noremap <F5> :w<CR> :silent !clear; make<CR> :!echo "--------------- Running ---------------"; echo; command time -v "./%<"<CR>`

Comment: Also, you can enforce that the name is the same as the filename (minus '.c') by using make variables (i.e. if the name of your program is stored in a variable called 'NAME', you can do `make NAME="%<"`). This means your Makefile can specify a different default name, but you can still use this shortcut in Vim.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line in your `vimrc` file

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :!clear;gcc % -o % && ./%<CR>
```

Now you only have to press f8 key to compile and run your c program.

Comment: Use %:r instead of % for last two %s or it'll overwrite your source file. I'd edit your answer but SO reviewers are in bad mood today.

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I would add this to these answers here. As has been mentioned, you can use the `:make` command in vim. What has not been mentioned yet, is that `:make` can invoke other programs, other than `make`.

```
:set makeprg=gcc\ %
```

Will cause `:make` to execute `gcc` with the `%` symbol replaced by the current file name.

You can then get fancy and do

```
:set makeprg=gcc\ %\ &&\ ./a.out
```

and simply typing `:make` will compile and execute your program. You can do this for other languages as well of course.

```
:set makeprg=cabal\ repl
:set makeprg=python\ %
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research (including this very page), I made my mind to add this shortcut:

```
map <F9> :w<CR> :!gcc % -o %<.x -Wall -Wextra 2>errors.err; cat errors.err<CR>
```

You can also include `-ansi -pedantic-errors` if you will.

The `errors.err` file will help you with vi quickfix.

Comment: so far the best *light weight* approach to compiling small cpp programs directly out of vim.

Answer (score 2):

I looked through all of these solutions and I found that they didn't work (as far as I could tell) for the case of editing a file in a different directory -- I wrote some vimscript that does this in a kinda clunky way, but hopefully someone can find this useful:

```
let mycommand = ':!gcc % -o %< && echo "%<" && [ $(pwd) == "." ] && %< || ./%< '
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :execute mycommand <CR>
```

or if the commands above work for you in multiple directories feel free to just ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth adding that [`SingleCompile`](http://singlecompile.topbug.net/) plugin offers that facility for C and other languages as stated by the author:

> SingleCompile is a Vim plugin aimed at making it more convenient to
>   compile or run a single source file without leaving Vim. Consider this
>   situation: you have just written a small C source file for a tiny
>   test, but you have to write a Makefile to compile it, or exit Vim to
>   compile it, or compile it using "!gcc" without quickfix feature
>   because Vim's make command only use the "make" command? This plugin
>   will help you out.

Suggested mappings for <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>:

```
nmap <F9> :SCCompile<cr>
nmap <F10> :SCCompileRun<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created command to Run my c & cpp codes

```
:command  Runcpp !clear;g++ % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR> 
:command  Runc   !clear;gcc % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

Put above code in .vimrc file and run you code using command Runcpp & Runc

Answer (score 1):

you Can easily compile and run your program from vim directly just go to normal mode and type

```
:!gcc yourProgramName.c
```

and then just simply write the following to run the program

```
:!gcc % | ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these three lines to your `.vimrc` file

```
au FileType c set makeprg=gcc\ % 

au FileType cpp set makeprg=g++\ %

map <F7>:make && ./a.out<CR>
```

You can compile and run your program by pressing the <kbd>F7</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F9> :w<CR> :!clear<CR> :!gcc % -o %< && %<<CR>
```

This will allow you to Compile/Run C with `<F9>` and clear console

You can also do the following:

```
autocmd filetype c nnoremap <F8> :w<CR> :!clear<CR> :!make && ./%<<CR>
```

This will allow you to Compile/Run C using Makefile with `<F8>` and clear console