# Compiling and Running a C++ Program with Vim

Tags: c++, vim

I know this sounds really dumb, but I've written a C++ code on Vim editor and for the life of me cannot figure out how to compile and run it.  I know this is extremely simple but I've been awake for far too long 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well... Vim is a text editor. You have to use a _compiler_ to compile your program ;-).

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627886/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-from-vim

Comment: You can see this [question][1], but using IDE would be better I think. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627886/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-from-vim

Comment: @SergeyKoklyuev Using an IDE or a text editor is a personal choice and cannot be better or worse. It might be easier because the OP sounds like a beginner (no offense intended).

Comment: You can add a map sequence to compile the single-source you are editing and add a sequence to run it. In my `~/.vimrc` I add `map \g <Esc>:!gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast -o %< % <CR>` which maps the compile to `\g` (accessed by `[ctrl]+v` then `\g`) Then to run the file, add a map for  `map \r <Esc>:!./%< <CR>` (accessed by `[ctrl]+v` then `\r`). So it's basically `\g` for `gcc` and `\r` to run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply type into `vim`:

```
:wq
```

then, on your command line, invoke the *compiler* which isn't `vim` but `g++` or `clang++` or something like:

```
g++ -o myCode myCode.cpp
```

EDIT: All you down voters please read section 21 of the vim user's manual by the man himself Bram Moolenaar entitled: "Go away and come back". `:help user-manual` will get you there.  Where he basically says it's cool to either compile in vim OR save and exit, compile, and then come back. By the title of the section I presume Bram prefers the later.  He most certainly has crafted vim to handle the later in a most excellent manner.  When I "come back" to any file: the cursor is at the same row and column, I can undo and redo as before, and all my history, searches, registers, and everything is exactly as I left it.  I basically can't see any difference from when I went away!

RE-EDIT: to all you down voters again - peeps use vim in so many different ways for so many different reasons.  I do so much at the shell level all the time that it would be painfully idiotic to remain continuously in vim.  You down voters obviously work in completely different situations where you are good to stay inside the editor. Please stop thinking all peeps work the same way as you do.

Comment: +1...thanks for reminding back..i completely forgot.how we use to do this  often during college labs..;)

Comment: This is not very vim. Closing and reopening vim everytime you want to compile is very inefficient. You're better off using a built-in command like `:make` (see my answer).

Comment: @Jon I've been using `vim` (since it was `vi`!) *very* effectively to develop code for blue-chip companies for decades(!) and this is how I roll... I consider `bash` a *much* useful tool for running `make` or what ever tool I want to use after editing a file.

Comment: @PaulEvans Your vim golf handicap must be horrific. But please, don't take offense. I'm not saying it's wrong to quit, just less efficient...our poor OP might have 50 buffers open...which of course, will go bye-bye.

Comment: @Jon the reason I use `vim` over *that other editor* is because I don't want to live inside an editing tool.  Having said that - I *love* `vim` and could show you things you couldn't image `vim` could do i.e. `ctrl-n`

Comment: At the very least just do `ctrl-z` to drop out of vim temporarily! and then `fg` to go back to what you were doing. That said, I close and reopen vim constantly. I consider it a bad habit though.

Comment: @method You won't have your latest edits stored that way.  `vim` is designed to be left and re-entered normally.  Look at `viminfo` for all kinds of things (history *etc*) that `vim` can remember about a file between edits.

Comment: Why al the downvotes?

Comment: @Blaze349. Let's put aside `$> make myCode`. The main reason I can see is that browsing hundreds, if not thousands, lines of errors and warnings in a C++ code in the console is extremely clumsy. One of the earlier feature of vim is its quickfix feature. I used to switch to the console to compile, or even to execute `:!make` on what I'm editing. But this was some 20ish years ago with vi. Not vim. I consider not using the qf feature to be an anti-pattern, in particular where C++ is concerned -- just try to send a new type or even a `vector` to `std::cout` without the proper overload.

Comment: @LucHermitte so you live inside vim, wow! what ever works for you I guess. I personally have tons of stuff to do besides editing and compiling. bash is the perfect environment for that.

Comment: @PaulEvans. I do many thing outside vim. The thing is that when I'm working on C++ code, I'd rather compile from within Vim. The reason being the numerous lines of errors (tracking mismatched parameters in template world is really complex). It's also extremely easy to ignore warnings when compiling in the console. So yes, I do use the quickfix feature. And yes, I clearly consider compiling in the console anything we're working on (and thus that may contain errors/warnings) is an workflow anti-pattern.

Comment: @LucHermitte guess my compile environments just works better in bash. And all you down voters please read section 21 of the vim user's manual by the man himself Bram Moolenaar entitled: "Go away and come back". where he basically say it's cool to either compile in vim or save and exit, compile, and then come back :P

Comment: @Jon please read the edit - I'm talking to you :P

Comment: @Jon please read the RE-EDIT as it is directed to peeps like you :P

Comment: To be pedantic, the questions states "with vim" and exiting vim isn't "with vim" any more. The irony of all of this is that I actually keep vim open but use a separate terminal to compile. Yet another way to skin the proverbial cat, and that is vim's strength - we get to choose. It was wrong of me to say it's not vim to exit, that's quite subjective anyway.

Comment: Its so much more efficient to have Vim parse the compile output.

Comment: @nenchev but I do have Vim parse the compile output! I tee it to a time stamped log cache and have bash tool that sorts them by time and fires up Vim to the first error line of the latest - or one of my choice :)

Comment: This is the wrong answer; everyone knows already how to do what this answer says to do; however, people want to know how not to do it this way; that is the precise question that was asked. However, what we are asking how not to do anymore is the check-marked answer. So that is why I am giving this answer a downvote.

Answer (score 45):

`:make` is indeed the way to go as [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391064/jon) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21474788/15934).

On Linux-like (it also applies to cygwin, but not to mingw on windows) systems where gnumake is installed, if you don't have a Makefile in your project, and if your project is made of only one file, just type `:make`. It will be enough (you can play with `$CXXFLAGS`, `$CFLAGS` and `$LDFLAGS` to tune the compilation options). Then to run the program, type `:!./%<` (IIRC).

If your project is made of several files, then you'll need a Makefile to take advantage of `:make`.

If you manage your project with CMake, and if you compile your project in a directory (or several -> debug, release, ...) outside the sources tree, then the integration will require a plugin. AFAIK, I'm the only one to propose such a plugin: [BuildToolsWrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/master/doc/cmake.md) integrates the management of CMake (choice of the build directory, possibility to chose between the debug, or release, or whatever build directory). It has to be coupled with one of the [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/local_vimrc.vim) plugin.

In all cases, calling directly the compiler from within (or outside) Vim with `:!g++ -o %< %` or whatever is what we used to do 15 years ago on vi. Vim has a wonderful feature: it can integrate (yes, like in IDE) the compiler. See `:h quickfix`. Navigating between errors directly from the editor is much easier than extracting one error line with our eyes, typing back the line number into the editor, going back to the shell to see what exactly was rejected, ... It may be enough in C, but In C++ when we are "trying to call an overload that doesn't exist", we can't work this way (switching back and forth between the editor and the shell).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This has saved me 5 seconds every 30mins of C/C++/Java Coding.

Answer (score 7):

This depends on how you build your software. If you're using make, you can enter `:make` in the vim prompt. Type `:h make` to see the options and supporting command that let you cycle through the errors in your code.

Comment: Text editors should be for manipulating text, Unix philosophy