# compile inside vim using special cmd

Tags: c++, vim

Is there any way for me to define a command (i.e :compile) to compile C/C++ code inside vim? I know I can use :!g++ %:p for that but is really tricky to type all these special characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling and Running a C++ Program with Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474662/compiling-and-running-a-c-program-with-vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:make` command in Vim. By default it runs `make` but you can set the `makeprg` variable to be whatever program you want.

So for your example.

```
:set makeprg=g++\ %
```

and then you can

```
:make
```

Comment: Non need to change makeprg to g++ on machines where gnu make is correctly configured (i.e. all *nixes but mingw)

Comment: The reason you change `makeprg` is because you don't want to use `make`, i.e. you don't have a Makefile. Changing `makeprg` to `g++\ %` calls `g++` directly on your source file, so it's good for quick experimenting.

Comment: We don't need to write a makefile to compile mono-file programs. The thing is that mono-file projects shall not be in directories where a Makefile already exists. Try, `mkdir test && cd test && gvim hello.cpp` , write an hello world program, and then, type `:make`.

Comment: That does not work for me. `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: Being able to skip make lets you use it for other kinds of projects as well, and that is useful. You can set `makeprg` to python or runhaskell or whatever you like. It doesn't have to be tied to `make`.

Comment: My mistake -- I have a plugin that does its best to autodetect the target when I use `:Make`, and thus I tend to forget how vanilla- vim works ^^'. It has to be `:make %<`.
I agree for the global case. But here, the OP is programming in C++. :)

Comment: Yeah, I often forget how vanilla vim works as well... .vimrc has grown over the years. In fact, the first thing I did once you said that was to run through my vimrc and check that I hadn't messed something up xD

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:make` (or abbreviation `:mak`) to invoke your `Makefile`. You can even specify a target (e.g. `:mak build`). And you can always make a mapping to make it (hehe) easier to invoke.

```
:help :make
```