# How to make building / compilation more comfortable

Tags: c++, vim, workflow, command-line-interface

My current workflow when developing Apps or programs with Java or C/C++ is as follows:

I don't use any IDE like IntelliJ, Visual Studio, ...
Using linux or OS X, I use vim as code editor. When I build with a makefile or (when in Java) gradle, I `:!make` and wait for the compiler and linker to create the executable, which will be run automatically.

In case of compilation errors, the output of the compiler can get very long and the lines exceed the columns of the console. So everything gets messy, and sometimes takes too much time to find out, what the first error ist (often causing all following compile errors).

My question is, what is your workflow as a C++ developer? For example is there a way, to generate a nicely formatted local html file, that you can view / update in your browser window. Or other ideas?

Yes, I know. I could use Xcode or any other IDE. But I just don't want.

Comment: Two monitors goes a long way. Vim on one side, build tools and testing on the other. If you abide by good column-width style, you can have two on one screen...

Comment: Most IDEs provide functionality for double-clicking on a compile error and displaying the file and placing cursor where the error is.  You don't get this with console / terminal development.

Comment: Pipe the output of compilers, linkers and make utility into a log file.  Open log file in your favorite editor.

Comment: I also do not use an IDE.  emacs (groan, yes, I know, huge learning curve) provides a *compilation* screen, where make files and compilation output are collected. It acts like an in-editor log buffer (and yes, you can save that to a file (and reload it!)).  The *compilation*  screen has the 'cursor-select-error-message-jumps-to-src-code' feature, which I use a lot.  I believe there is an add-on for "auto-complete" feature, but I don't use it.  CUA emulation? I think so, but I don't use it either.  emacs is close to being a 'no-mouse-needed' editor ... which I value.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you. I can imagine this as a good starting point. You could even use a script that parses that output, marks it as HTML with colors, or the use of tables, etc. But perhaps anyone has found out a workflow or a tool that is capable of that, already. Say, a compromise with having both worlds. CLI simplicity and an efficient way to see and realize whats going wrong in that state of developing.

Comment: My peers at my last contract used vi.  No IDE.  They had three or more screens for each effort in work at same time.  One for editing, one for compiler/linker output, and a third for running the debugger.  This worked well on the Sun Solaris systems they were using.  They often were working on 3 or more efforts at same time, and used fonts smaller than my bifocals could reach.  The better coders were very impressive.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN That sounds good. Too bad, I don't use emacs. But ThomasMatthews' comment is essentially what happens to create your log buffer. Except I will be missing that cool 'cursor-select-error-message-jumps-to-src-code' feature. Perhaps someone will write a plugin ...

Comment: I have not looked at it much, since vim and vi do not appeal to me, but you might check out emacs vim emulation (... maybe called  "Evil".  Gotta be.)

Comment: "So everything gets messy, ..."  smaller fonts?  bigger screen? multiple screens.

Comment: "is there a way, to generate a nicely formatted local html file, that you can view / update in your browser window."  Have you looked yet?  I found at lease one tool for "Capture Compiler Output".  Probably more, if you look.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, What do you mean by "generate a local html file", There is no such beast when compiling C++ programs. At best, we can generate the doxygen documentation in HTML, but it's best done in the Makefile or the CMakefiles. Then, it simply becomes a new target for make, and thus for the IDE.

Comment: @LucHermitte    Doug Moen did not say that.  The first line of his previous comment was a quote from the OP.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN. My mistake, I've confuse you with the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling in vim with `:!make` instead of `:make` doesn't make any sense -- it's even one of the early features of vim. The former will expect us to have good eyes. The latter will display compilation errors into the quickfix window, which we can navigate. In other words, no need to use an auxiliary log file: we can navigate compilation errors even in (a coupled of) editors that run into a console.

I did expand on a related topic in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934.

Regarding compilation, there are a few plugins that permits to compile in background. I've added this facility in [build-tool-wrapper](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) lately (it requires vim 7.4-1980 -- and it's still in a development branch at this time). This plugin also permits me to easily filter errors in the standard library with the venerable [STLfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html), and to manage several build configurations (each in a separate directory).