# Compiling a C++ program in Vim

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vim

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, with Vim

Can't find a way to compile and run my C++ program in Vim.
I have appended this to my vimrc file

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :!clear;gcc % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

from this question: [How do I run a C program from VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627886/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-from-vim/2650621#2650621)
But it isn't working - my program doesnt seem to compile when I press F8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with a simple `map` command like in the link. Get that working. Then, gradually add options back until it breaks or you get what you want. Also, you could leave off the `clear` to start. Also, when in `vim`, type `:map<CR>` to verify that the mapping of your command was accepted as you wanted.

Comment: :map<CR> says no mapping found.

Comment: It didn't accept your `.vimrc` command (i.e. no map for `F8`). Is `nnoremap` literally in your file or just a typo here? AFAICT, the command is `noremap`. You could try to manually enter your command when in `vim` and see if it shows up in the map and then test it to see if it works. Then, when you have the working version, add it to `.vimrc`

Comment: nnoremap was literally in my file. I had copied the command from somewhere. Changed it to noremap, but same problem persists. Somehow my source files are getting deleted. I guess ill debug this tomorrow.

Comment: Your source is getting deleted? If so, I'll hazard a guess. [_Caveat:_ I use `tcsh` and not `sh`]. I'm assuming that if your file were `foo.c`, then you want `%:r` to be `foo` [just like a shell]. Verify this by putting `echo` in front of `gcc` (i.e. `echo gcc % -o %:r`) and see what you get. I'll bet `%:r` comes up as `foo.c`

Comment: nope, it says invalid expression. Edit: I tried !echo gcc % -o %:r , and it returned gcc s.cpp -o s

Comment: The `echo` test says that `%:r` does what you'd like it to do. So, that's one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gone for the vim way of doing things. In particular in C++.

Calling `g++` from `:!` instead of `:make` is really counter-productive (`:h quickfix`).

Follow this path instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934 (1), unless you are under windows with the poorly configured make from MingW, in which case, follow this path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22452184/15934

(1) If you want a mapping, it would be something like:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :update<cr>:make %<<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I looked at the answer from the link and I can compile now. But having some trouble with running the compiled file. if i type !%< it says file not found under the bash folder

Comment: @novice It's a shell issue now. As your system is correctly configured, the current directory in not in your `$PATH`. As such to run the executable, type `:!./%<`. Don't forget the `./`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a makefile and then add 
`nmap <F8> :make!<CR>:cw<CR>` to your vimrc file

Comment: Unless he's using gnumake package shipped with MinGW, he doesn't need a `makefile` for mono-file projects. Try `:make %<`, you'll see. More details are available in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934