# Executing C code with F5 key in Vim

Tags: c, vim, autocmd

I want to save and execute my codes that's written in C programming language with just pressing F5 key in vim (in normal mode).

So I added this line to .vimrc file :

```
:autocmd FileType c nnoremap <F5> <Esc>:w!<CR>:!clear && gcc %<CR> && ./<CR>
```

But it doesn't work ! (It's make .Out file but it isn't run that file)

How can I do that's purpose with editing .vimrc file?

Comment: `./` will not run your file; `./a.out` should. You should also use `nnoremap <buffer> <F5>` so that your other buffers don't inherit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType c
   \ set makeprg=gcc\ -Wall\ %\ -o\ output |
   \ nnoremap  <special> <buffer> <F5> :w!<cr>:make<cr>:!./output
```

With this form you use `:make` alone for compiling.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the output.

Comment: i was test it but it's not work . it just build a output file but it's not run the output file

Comment: Why not add `:Copen` option for easy debugging in case of error

Comment: It is `:copen` with lowercase and what wants the OP actually is to run the exe file.

Comment: Don't override `&makeprg`. Unless you're using mingw distribution, this is counter productive. `:make %<` is enough -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934. Then the execution of the result should be conditioned to the success of the compilation. Unfortunately `v:shell_error` isn't updated with `:make`result. We have to rely on tricks that don't fit in one-line (see latex-suite, build-tool-wrapper, and a question somewhere on SO or vi.SE on the subject). Last thing: the mapping should be `<buffer>` local

Answer (score 0):

Plug `skywind3000/asyncrun.vim`

- Open quickfix window automatically when AsyncRun is executed.
- Set the quickfix window 6 lines height.

  ```
  let g:asyncrun_open = 6
  ```
- Ring the bell to notify you job finished.

  ```
  let g:asyncrun_bell = 1
  ```
- F10 to toggle quickfix window.

  ```
  nnoremap <F10> :call asyncrun#quickfix_toggle(6)<cr>
  ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).