# make from within vim

Tags: vim, makefile, compilation, cmake

I am using gvim for coding c++. Since my program involves cmake, my sources are located in a different directory than my build.

How can I still invoke :make from within vim so that the correct make file within the build directory is found?

how can I then subsequently start my application with the very same command line style and one keystroke?

Answer (score 3):

TD;LR: just assign `'cd "compi/dir" && make $*'` to `&makeprg` (with `:let`) and run `:make youroptionaltarget -j 4`.

In another [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934), I've already criticised the `:!make` approach. This is what we had to do 20-ish years ago with vi. Vim has introduced integrated compilation through quickfix mode. Please learn vim way to compile code.

In CMake case, we can indeed compile with `cmake --someoption compil/dir`. I use it when I compile with VC++ compiler, piloted by CMake, from vim. The rest of the time, I'd rather avoid it as it messes compiler outputs by prepending each line with `number>`, which breaks vim quickfix feature. Unfortunately there is no neat way to ignore this noise by tweaking `&errorformat`. So far I postprocess `cmake` and `ctest` outputs to remove `^\d+>`.

So. What can, and shall, we really do? We should take advantage of vim quickfix feature. This is done by tweaking `&makeprg` and `&efm` options. In your case, the first one should be enough. Use it to change directory and execute `make`. And finally compile with `:make` and navigate errors with `:cn`, `:cp`, `:cc`, etc.

If you want also to compile in background, you'll need a plugin that knows how to compile in background in a directory which is not the current one. This is where I advertise my [build-tool-wrappers plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) that provides these features and a few more CMake related features.

PS: It's also possible to use `make` (and ninja) `-c` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I came up with is the following:

```
:! (cd /path/to/your/cmake/build/directory; make)
```

To execute the program at the same time, you can append commands with `;` or `&&`:

```
:! (cd /path/to/your/cmake/build/directory; make && ./myProgram)
```

In [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)), you can find a tutorial how to bind this in order to do this in one key stroke.

**Explanation:**

In vim, you can execute any command with `:! command` (for instance, `:! ls`). 
With `(cd [...]; [...])`, you specify that the execution directory is different by creating a subshell and changing to this directory in the subshell.

Comment: all right thank you. I will key bind this then to make life easier

Comment: using `cmake --build <path to build dir>` (or in this case after the `cd` command `cmake --build .`) is independent of the generated tool files (could use the same to invoke `ninja` if we've selected to generate files for it).

Moreover, you can use a `.vimrc.local` at the root dir of your project and have the `makeprg` or other project specific commands set there. You will need to add something like this in your main `.vimrc`

`if filereadable($HOME . "/.vimrc.local")
  source ~/.vimrc.local
endif`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F8> :w<CR> :!clear<CR> :!make && ./%<<CR>
```

This will allow you to Compile/Run C++ using Makefile with `<F8>` and clear console