# getchar() is not called when the program is executed via nvim in C

Tags: c, vim, user-input, neovim

I am a novice C programmer currently designing simple programs based on books to get more knowledge.
Right now, I am studying "The C Programming Language" (Brian Kernighan, Dennis Ritchie) and I'm hitting the section discussing about input/output programming.

Here is the code I am trying to run (almost exact copy from K&R):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;

    printf("Input character:\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }

    printf("End of code\n");

    return 0;

}
```

I use **nvim** as my IDE. I set my nvim shortcuts as follow for the compilation:

```
nnoremap <leader>cc :!gcc -Wall % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

Now back to the code. When I compile this one using the shortcut showed above, it works just fine. the code compiles. However, my program ends without asking me for any input (as the call to getchar() should do):

```
:!gcc -Wall inputoutput.c -o inputoutput && ./inputoutput

Input character:
End of code
```

Typing the command directly in nvim, without any subsitution:

```
:gcc -Wall inputoutput.c -o inputoutput && ./inputoutput
```

Gives me the same output as before.

However, when I execute the compiled program *outside* nvim, I get the expected behavior:

```
nxr: ~/scratch/c - ./inputouput
Input character:
a
a
** <CTRL-d> **
End of code

nxr: ~/scratch/c -
```

My questions are:

1. **Why the behavior within nvim and outside is different when I try running the code?**
2. **What should I change in my C code or my nvim macro in order to obtain the expected behavior when running the program within nvim?**

Comment: Presumably, when it fails, you are getting EOF from `getchar()` on the first call.  This might be a time to break out `feof(stdin)` to see whether you're getting a EOF (e.g. because the input is coming from `/dev/null`) or some error.  After the loop, before the `printf()`: `if (feof(stdin)) printf("EOF\n"); else printf("Error\n");`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler After applying the change described in your first comment, I have the EOF output coming out (not the Error one). For "<", according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627886/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-from-vim): "  "<" after "%" removes extension and dot (foo.c => foo), so "%<" is the file basename. " (ungalnanban answer)

Comment: It appears that, for some reason, your input is coming from `/dev/null` or equivalent, or some other empty file.  Odd!  I'll need to cogitate for a while.  Are you on Linux, perchance?  (I found out about the `%<` via `:help %<` — I should have looked first.  Note that's a backwards compatibility hack; the preferred form is `%:r`.  But that's a new feature to me, so thanks for that.)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm on Linux. I'll make the change on my vim config file to reflect the preferred form. Should not change a thing, but it won't harm anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering what the significance of `nvim` is. It's unlikely to be the cause of your trouble. I'm trying to think of a simple way to detect whether standard input is in fact `/dev/null` or something else. That can be done with an `fstat()` function call plus dissecting what it returns (and a `stat()` call also), but that's not trivial to write, unlike my previous suggestion.  Not rocket science, but not trivial.  What you're seeing is unexpected — but not the fault of the C code you're running.  It is something to do with `nvim`, somehow.  What happens if you type `:!%:r` and then return?

Comment: I can't reproduce with vim on a Mac, which isn't much help.  I'm updating my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM image — I had to rejig the network and catch up on a month's updates.  It didn't seem to have `nvim` either.  Plain `vim` on the Mac is Vim 7.4 at the moment (`vim --version` — lots of information in the output).

Comment: [nvim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Introduction) (neovim) is a refactor version of vim. If I type `:!%:r`, I have a empty line followed by "command not found inputoutput" (expected behavior). But this newline is weird.. I tried with vi, and I'm not having a new line.

Comment: I keep `.` on my path; I don't work in hostile enough environments for it to be a problem to me.  I meant `:!./%:r`'.  However, it looks like you've found the problem — it is a design decision by `nvim`.  I think that means I won't be using `nvim`; certainly, it would have to be fantastically better than plain `vim` to warrant putting up with that (mis)behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your help on the topic. Seems like the neovim team is working on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Neovim bang character introduces a EOF, as explained [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496).
2. Change the ! in the macro by "te".

Answer (score -1):

In gvim, :!gcc -Wall inputoutput.c -o inputoutput && ./inputoutput 
works for me and runs the program in the lower screen.

Not sure what the nnoremap is doing, but there must be some control character getting introduced.  I usually don't use editor remaps like that.  Suggest writing a Makefile and just make run

Comment: I typed the command directly within nvim (i.e. without using my shortcut with nnoremap), and I still cannot get any user input. Some additional piece of info, I'm running nvim v0.2.0. I can eventually write a Makefile and make it work. I can also directly compile outside nvim anyway. But for convenience, I'd like to find a way to have this one working.

Comment: That's not an answer, but a comment. Actually it is a close reason: "cannot reproduce"