# Cannot compile and run a c program using vim

Tags: c, vim

`map <F5> : !gcc % && ./%< <CR>`

This is supposed to map the F5 key for compiling my c code and executing it with the same name of the file without extension. It's all fine, the compilation part has no error, however as soon as the `./%` part is to be operated.

I am getting a command line message of `'.' is not recognized as internal or external command`.

The same happens when I am using `map <F10> :w<CR> :!clear; make<CR> :!./%<<CR>`. I really don't know how this `make` thing works or what it is. I tried out a plugin `Asyncrun`.

Yet I am having the same issue. what could be possible cause of it and how to solve it.

Comment: And [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) has a very good documentation, that you could read. Also read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). You want to compile your C code with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: You could consider using the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C software project. Or perhaps [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)

Comment: I use `map \g <Esc>:!gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast -o %< % <CR>` which maps to  **Ctrl + v \ g**  (chose **\ g** short for `gcc`) It compiles to the executable with the same name as the current file minus the `".c"`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "Have a problem with Vim? Nah just use emacs" ???

Comment: I highly suspect the OP is under Windows (+MinGW quite likely) given [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627886/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-from-vim/35702919?noredirect=1#comment114595701_35702919). This means, instead of `./%` we have `%:ph` that should do the trick. And If my hypothesis about MinGW is correct then GNUMakefile won't be properly  configured. In the end, the Vim way will be to directly call the compiler from the `&makeprg` option. (`:!gcc` being 25ish years old vi (without m) way of doing things)

Comment: @LucHermitte yes your assumption is correct, I tried out the `%:ph` instead of `./%` nothing really worked out. This is the result C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (E:\learning_c\class_c\Uppercase.ch)
'E:\learning_c\class_c\Uppercase.ch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AnaghBasak an extremely long time ago (Window95 era) I've been fighting with Vim default settings on Windows. At that time I came up with that [solution](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-system-tools/blob/master/plugin/system_utils.vim#L268). So far It still seems to work. You can try to change the default `shellxxxxx` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution typically for windows under MINGw. `GCC` is the name of the compiler application. So the idea is to call `gcc` and provide it with the name of the file which is to be compiled. The name means the complete path to the file with the file name and extension.

Then we can either execute the `a.out` file or rename the executable file with the name of the actual file without the extension. So gcc has `-o` for renaming files. The last job is to call the executable.

`:!gcc % :! gcc % -o %< :! %<` This is the total command. One can map all these commands on to one key or separate them as per their needs. `:!` opens the command line in VIM. `%` is the name of the file with the exact file path. In `%<` the `<` just curtails the file extension.

This is what I have put in my vimrc file.

`map <F2> :! gcc % <CR>`

`map <F3> :! gcc % -o %< <CR>`

`map <F4> :! %< <CR>`